# In Python, why are the time complexities different between set operations union, intersection, and symmetric difference?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, set, time-complexity

According to the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) these are the average case time complexities for the following set operations between 2 sets s and t:

- union: O(s+t)
- intersection: O(min(s, t))
- difference: O(s)
- symmetric difference: O(s)

The time complexities for intersection and difference make sense to me, but I don't understand why the time complexities for union and symmetric difference aren't the same as the time complexity for intersection (O(min(s, t)).

If we called s the smaller set and t the larger set, then wouldn't the following logic for union and symmetric difference both have time complexities of (O(min(s, t))? If this is not how these 2 operations are done under the hood in python then why is that?

```
# Symmetric Difference
for element in s:
  if element in t:
    t.remove(element)
  else:
    t.add(element)
return t

# Union
for element in s:
  t.add(element)
return t
```

Comment: Wouldn't union be adding every element of each set to a **new set**? Not just adding every element of one set to the other. So O(len(s) + len(t)) makes sense.

Comment: The union of two sets is at least as large as either argument. It might help if I told you that `O(s + t)` is another way of writing `O(max(s, t))`.

Comment: Symmetric difference doesn't modify set `t`; it builds a *new* set based the lookup of each value of `s` in `t`. Think about how many lookups that entails, and what the complexity of each look up is.

Comment: @chepner Shouldn't symmetric difference take O(s+t)? It's symmetric, after all. Can't just depend on one but not the other.

Comment: @superbrain Yeah, I was thinking of asymmetric difference. I'll note, though, that on average, `s` is the larger set half the time, so `O(s+t) == O(s)` :)

Comment: (Even that's not right. Probably something like `s + t = O(s)` on average, I don't know. Average-case complexity makes my head hurt.)

Comment: @chepner so are you saying in this case O(s+t) and O(s) can be used interchangeably?

Comment: I *was* saying that, but I'm not convinced. Sometimes O(s+t) = O(s), sometimes it equals O(t) (depending on which is larger. I *think* you can argue that on average, it could be equal to either, but like I said, averge-case complexity makes my head hurt.

Comment: @chepner If that's the argument, then the page should say O(s) for union as well, not O(s+t). The page is at the very least inconsistent. But I think it's just wrong. It should say O(s+t), just like for union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Union](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1264d0465ad77019a43ff8c1f8d329b17f049f80/Objects/setobject.c#L1106)

Consider two sets `s` and `t`. In order to build a new set which represent the union of `s` and `t` you need to iterate over them. This results in a time complexity of `O(len(s) + len(t))`.

```
def union(s, t):
   """Simple example for union, ignoring error-handling on inputs, etc."""
   result = set(s)   # copy: O(len(s))
   for el in t:      # iterate over t: O(len(t))
      result.add(el) # ignoring collisions, O(1) amortized time
   return result
```

#### [Symmetric Difference](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1264d0465ad77019a43ff8c1f8d329b17f049f80/Objects/setobject.c#L1647)

```
def symmetric_difference(s, t):
   """Simple example for symmetric difference, ignoring error-handling on inputs, etc."""
   result = set(t)        # copy: O(len(t))
   for el in s:           # iterate over s: O(len(s))
      if el not in t:    
        result.add(el)
      else:
        result.remove(el)
   return result
```

What CPython does, is to start from a copy of `t`, then iterate over `s` and add or remove element from the output set according to the result of the lookup.
Also in this case assuming the amortized time complexity for the lookup to be  O(1), the resulting time complexity should be `O(len(s) + len(t))`, as for the union.

The table indicates a different time complexity for the **average** time complexity of the symmetric difference as `O(s)` and the reason might be that they ignore the time complexity of the `make_new_set` function (which builds a new set starting from `t`).